# Pixel 7 lock screen timer

Tags: lock-screens, battery-life, google-pixel

I would like to have the lock screen on a Google Pixel 7 to display for a specific time before powering off the screen.

This should not be confused with the screen timeout (normal screen > lock screen).  This question is about the specific timer that powers-off the screen once the lock screen is showing (lock screen > no power consumption by the screen).

There is a setting "Always show time and info", which is the opposite of what I want to do (battery waster, not battery saver), so that's "off", of course.

What I would expect is two timers.  One for (normal screen > lock screen), which I was able to find, and one for (lock screen > no power consumption by the screen).

Note that apps that simply place a black background on the screen aren't turning the power off to the screen, so that's not a solution.

Where can I change (limit) the amount of time that the lock screen is consuming power?

Comment: On my 6a, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkQ8M.png) setting does it, but of course it's not a timer

Comment: Edited the heading to make it consistent with body of question. You can roll back if you disagree

Answer (score 1):

If the "Always show time and info" is OFF, then after the phone is locked, the lock screen is only consuming power for a few seconds.  This duration is not customizable.